# Using ElasticRTC with custom AMI

Tags: opencv, amazon-web-services, autoscaling, kurento

I am using [elasticrtc](https://github.com/ElasticRTC) to launch my kurento application into AWS. However, I have my custom OpenCV module that I created for Kurento Media Server which I manually installed to all my instances (not ideal). I want the module to be installed when the AutoScaling policy launches a new instance since I wont have the chance to manually install anymore.

Can I launch the elasticRTC stack with a custom AMI Image?
OR
Can I edit the launchConfiguration to install my module (*.deb module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: not at the moment

Long answer: if you modify the startup script, you can set the AMI. I think it's [here](https://github.com/ElasticRTC/elasticrtc-tools/blob/master/tools/elasticrtc#L987) the name of the param you'll need to change.

Comment: thanks Ivan. 

What is the best way so far to implement a custom kurento processing module using the elasticrtc script ?

I like how it uses hazelcast to create a cluster, its just what I need.

Comment: @geekInMe You mean a KMS module that you can deploy in with your Kurento Media Server instance?

Comment: I have developed an OpenCV module for KMS. which works perfectly if I install it on **manually** on my elasticRTC deployed instances.
Can i **automate** this installation somehow?

Comment: @geekInMe You'll need to generate your own instance, and change the instance type in the location pointed in the answer. Sorry, not very freandly for now :-(